# as3 swap depth movieclips in fullscreen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

hi I asked this question yesterday but I found out that my problem is using fullscreen

my goal is 2 mc 2 buttons :
if btn 1 is clicked mc1 fullscreen and mc2 appears at the right bottom corner on top of mc1
if btn 2 is clicked mc2 fullscreen and mc1 appears at the right bottom corner on top of mc2

stage.swapChildren or setChildIndex is the way but with the fullScreen I had this error appears

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
>       at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/swapChildren()
>       at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/setFullscreen()
>       at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/full()
>       at flash.display::Stage/set_displayState()
>       at flash.display::Stage/set displayState()
>       at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/goFullScreen()
>       at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/goLiveFullScreen()

how can I fix this ???

Comment: The error above popups up probably because you are using swapChildren on the wrong place. I.e. are you sure that the both movie clips are children of the object for which you are calling swapChildren.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is swapChildren requires a parent/child relationship, and the child you're trying to move isn't a child of what you're calling.

This might be clearer if you imagine MovieClips as folders on your hard drive.  By default `swapChildren()` called on its own will refer to the MainTimeline of your document.

For example `swapChildren(A, B)` actually translates to `this.swapChildren(A, B)`

If your stage hierarchy looked like this...

```
stage.videoPlayer.mc1
stage.videoPlayer.mc2
```

Then you would type:

```
videoPlayer.swapChildren(mc1, mc2)
```